# Requests sent from Advanced Rest Client for Chrome are not visible in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, advanced-rest-client

I have a Web API application running locally. When I access it through a browser, the requests are visible in Fiddler. When I do it through the Advanced Rest Client for Chrome - nothing appears in Fiddler.

I am using IIS Express with localhost.

How do I make requests issued by ARC visible in Fiddler?

Comment: The app is just making regular http request. Maybe it needs some headers? I mean server?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with https://graph.facebook.com/test and it worked fine for me after making some setup changes. Here is what I have setup:

1. IE > Internet options > Connection > Lan Settings > 
   a. Automatically detect - Check
   b. Use proxy server for your lan - check with fiddler host and port for http/s
2. Advanced Rest Client with ARC ( Without ARC it wont even be able to connect)
3. Fiddler > File > Capture Traffic

It worked even for the extension Postman (without even needing ARC).

Can you try these?

Comment: I assume your "Bypass proxy for local" option is unchecked